# Is it ok to use more viscous oil with old engines that burn oil?

Tags: oil, pontiac, vibe, oil-consumption

My old 2009 Pont Vibe uses lots of oil. One common explanation seems to be leaky piston rings. The manual and motor states SAR 5W20. A mechanic told me I should use 10W40 instead because it’s more viscous and would not leaks quickly. He said the type of oil in the manual is correct but really only applies when the engine is new (or not as old).

Is he right? Should I use 10W40 to avoid topping up so much?

And just to make sure, if so, I should NOT mix it but do a complete oil change?